# How can I simplify my if condition in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, simplify

I would like to know if there's a simpler way to write the condition of the `if` statement. Something like `item1, item2 == "wood":`. I currently have this code:

```
item1 = input("item1: ")
item2 = input("item2: ")

if item1 == "wood" and item2 == "wood":
    print("You created a stick")
```

Comment: There are other ways to write it, yes. Whether those ways are simpler, that's in the eye of the beholder. For two items, I'd leave it as is: it's clear and concise enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a huge savings but you could take out `"wood" and`

```
item1 = input("item1: ")
item2 = input("item2: ")

if item1 == item2 == "wood":
    print("You created a stick")
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, it's fine to leave it as is. But if you have three or more elements, try using a list:

```
items = [] # Declare a list

# Add items to list
for x in range(1, 4):
    items.append(input("item" + str(x) + ": "))

if all(item == "wood" for item in items):
    print("You created a stick")
```

Comment: ...although your example only goes from 1 to 2.

Comment: @TimPietzcker So does OP's. ;) Just kidding, that was unintentional.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways. you can use "==" for two variables.

```
item1 = input("item1: ")
item2 = input("item2: ")

if item1 == item2 == "wood":
    print("You created a stick")
```

And also you can do using a for loop. But for that you have to use a list first.So this would help if you are using huge number of inputs.

```
list1=[]
item1 = (input("item1: "))
item2 = (input("item1: "))

list1.append(item1)
list1.append(item2)

if all(item=="wood" for item in list1):
    print("You created a stick")
```